# Preview in TextMate 2 scrolls to the top each time it is refreshed

Tags: forward-inverse-search, textmate, pdfsync

On my Mac I am using BasicTeX and TextMate 2 with the LaTeX bundle. I can typeset my document and display a PDF preview from within TextMate using the "Typeset & View" shortcut, but it scrolls the preview to the top each time I do so.

I tried modifying the bundle preferences to add the `-synctex=1` argument to `pdflatex`, but then TextMate just stalls when typesetting. If I try to use the "Jump to Current Line in Viewer," it tells me TextMate doesn't support `pdfsync`.

Is there an ideal way to set up TextMate for live updates and synchronized editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextMate supports SyncTeX via Skim:

1. Download and install [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net)
2. Open Skim, go to “Skim” → “Preferences…” → “Sync” and choose “TextMate” as Preset

   [image: Skim Preferences]
3. Open TextMate
4. Go to “TextMate” → “Preferences…” → “Terminal” and install “Shell Support”

   [image: Shell Support]
5. Go to “Bundles” → “LaTeX” → “Preferences”
6. Choose Skim as PDF Viewer (“View In: Skim”)

   [image: LaTeX Bundle Preferences]
7. The shortcut for SyncTeX in TextMate is <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (“Jump to Current Line in Viewer”). In Skim you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> and left-click to jump to the corresponding location in your current LaTeX document.
8. **Bonus:** Check out the paragraph “SyncTeX” in the [bundle documentation](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/blob/master/Support/help/Help.pdf) (also available in TextMate via “Bundles” → “LaTeX” → “Help”)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'll give it a shot. I heard about Skim but I was hesitant to install another PDF viewer when TextMate has one built in and the system ships with one as well. 

In my brief testing, it seems that it does work better, but still scrolls around; for instance I turned on "Watch Document" (which I can now use) and whenever I save in TextMate, the Skim view jumps around.

Comment: Can you clarify the need for Latexmk for accomplishing this? Note that it isn't installed with BasicTeX, but I installed it with `sudo tlmgr install latexmk`

Comment: If you want to use “Watch Document”, then you have to install `latexmk`. If you use “Typeset & View (PDF)”, then you do not need the command. However I strongly recommend Latexmk to everyone that uses (La)TeX.